# how can i extract last digit from input in java

Tags: java

```
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("nomber");
       int n= in.nextInt();
       int s= n*n;
       int l = (""+s).length();
       System.out.println(l);


    }
}
```

how can I extract last digit from input in a simple way. Not so complicated like while loop.... java

Answer (score 0):

Since last digit is also the remainder of dividing by 10, you can use `n % 10`.

Comment: but what if the input number more than 3 digits

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to extract last digit is modulo to 10. Example: 123 % 10 = 3
After that, if you want to continue to extract last digit (it's 2 in this case), you should assign number = number /10 that will return the remain of the number.

```
// Example n = 123
int lastDigit_1 = n % 10; // This will return 3
n = n /10 // This will return 12 because 123 / 10 = 12
int lastDigit2 = n % 10; // This will return 2
n = n /10 // This will return 1
int lastDigit3 = n % 10;
...
```

To implement the above concept, u should try using while loop for better approach.

Using while:

```
while(n != 0){
   someVariable = n % 10;
   // YOUR LOGIC HERE
   n = n / 10;
}
```